# Categorise hour into four different slots of 15 mins

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I am working on a dataframe and I want to group the data for an hour into 4 different slots of 15 mins,

0-15 - 1st slot
15-30 - 2nd slot
30-45 - 3rd slot
45-00(or 60) - 4th slot

I am not even able to think, how to go forward with this

[image: Here is the dataframe]

I tried extracting hours, minutes and seconds from the time, but what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division by `15` and then add `1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'M': range(60)})

df['slot'] = df['M'] // 15 + 1
```

---

```
print (df)
     M  slot
0    0     1
1    1     1
2    2     1
3    3     1
4    4     1
5    5     1
6    6     1
7    7     1
8    8     1
9    9     1
10  10     1
11  11     1
12  12     1
13  13     1
14  14     1
15  15     2
16  16     2
17  17     2
18  18     2
19  19     2
20  20     2
21  21     2
22  22     2
23  23     2
24  24     2
25  25     2
26  26     2
27  27     2
28  28     2
29  29     2
30  30     3
31  31     3
32  32     3
33  33     3
34  34     3
35  35     3
36  36     3
37  37     3
38  38     3
39  39     3
40  40     3
41  41     3
42  42     3
43  43     3
44  44     3
45  45     4
46  46     4
47  47     4
48  48     4
49  49     4
50  50     4
51  51     4
52  52     4
53  53     4
54  54     4
55  55     4
56  56     4
57  57     4
58  58     4
59  59     4
```